# Object param is not binding spring boot + angular2

Tags: angular, spring-boot, binding

Im trying to do a http POST request to an api made in srping boot from an angular app. The api spect an object as parameter, when execute the url with postman with form-data or urlenconde param the solicitud finish ok but with de angular call the object is not binding.

My angular code is:

```
 opciones(): RequestOptionsArgs {
let headers: Headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });

// headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

let options: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions();

options.headers = headers;

return options;
}

UserById(param: Object): any {
console.log(JSON.stringify(param));
return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/user/userbyid', JSON.stringify(param), this.opciones()).pipe(
  map((res: Response) => {
    return res.json();
  }),
);
```

}

Im trying sending the param object as json and without parse and the result is the same. An example of the object:

```
{"User":"leonardo_alvarez","User2":"Usuario2"}
```

My spging boot code is:

```
public class userObj {

    private String user;
    private String user2;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getUser2() {
        return user2;
    }

    public void setUser2(String user2) {
        this.user2 = user2;
    }
}

@Autowired
private REL_UserRepository rel_userRepository;
@PostMapping(path = "/userbyid")
public @ResponseBody List<REL_User> getUser (userObj User){
    return rel_userRepository.findByUserid(User.getUser());
}
```

The request execute fine witout error in the console. But the User object stay null.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b69ab.png)

Anny suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you get an error in the JavaScript console when you try to do this POST?

Comment: Hi, no the request execute without error. I added an image in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `@RequestBody` annotation from the parameter in the controller.

It should be like:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/userbyid")
public @ResponseBody List<REL_User> getUser (@RequestBody userObj User){
    return rel_userRepository.findByUserid(User.getUser());
}
```

But please note that you are going against the Java conventions with improperly naming the classes and parameters which obviously makes it harder to understand your code.

Comment: i try with @RequestBody annotation and i get the error: "Unsupported Media Type". Its my firs aplication in  java i need lern more about conventions.